# REST services does'n load in jboss AS 7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

i'm trying to make some REST services with a JBOSS AS7 but when I try to access them the logs says 404.
I been looking for solutions but doesn't found the solution.
The services are in a WAR project, which is in a EAR file to make the deploy in the JBOSS.

I'm using CXF and CDI to make the services.
The JBOSS has the version 3.0.5 of EasyRest.

This is the pom.xml of the WAR project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectWARModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>projectWARModule Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.apache.cxf.version>3.0.0</org.apache.cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-integration-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-wsdl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>projectWAR</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml of the EAR package, it have a reference to a JAR because in a tutorial I found about making EAR with maven it says to use it, but doesn't have anything:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>projectEARModule</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectJARModule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectWARModule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>projectEar</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This class is named PeopleRestService and have the services:

```
package com.example.rs;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.services.PeopleService;

@Path( "/people" )
public class PeopleRestService {


@Inject private PeopleService peopleService;

    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    @GET
    public Collection< Person > getPeople( @QueryParam( "page") @DefaultValue( "1" ) final int page ) {
        return peopleService.getPeople( page, 5 );
    }

    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    @Path( "/{email}" )
    @GET
    public Person getPerson( @PathParam( "email" ) final String email ) {
        return peopleService.getByEmail( email );
    }

    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  } )
    @POST
    public Response addPerson( @Context final UriInfo uriInfo,
            @FormParam( "email" ) final String email, 
            @FormParam( "firstName" ) final String firstName, 
            @FormParam( "lastName" ) final String lastName ) {

        final Person person = peopleService.addPerson( email, firstName, lastName );
        return Response.created( uriInfo.getRequestUriBuilder().path( email ).build() ).entity( person ).build();
    }

    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  } )
    @Path( "/{email}" )
    @PUT
    public Person updatePerson(         
            @PathParam( "email" ) final String email, 
            @FormParam( "firstName" ) final String firstName, 
            @FormParam( "lastName" )  final String lastName ) {

        final Person person = peopleService.getByEmail( email );

        if( firstName != null ) {
            person.setFirstName( firstName );
        }

        if( lastName != null ) {
            person.setLastName( lastName );
        }

        return person;              
    }

    @Path( "/{email}" )
    @DELETE
    public Response deletePerson( @PathParam( "email" ) final String email ) {
        peopleService.removePerson( email );
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

And this is named JaxRsApiApplication:

```
package com.example.rs;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

@ApplicationPath( "api" )
public class JaxRsApiApplication extends Application {

}
```

This is the beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

And this is the web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PeopleRestService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.cdi.CXFCdiServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.cxf.cdi</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.rs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PeopleRestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I try run this in a tomcat works perfectly, but in JBOSS only get a 404.
I think could be a problem with the libraries, but don't know what problem especificaly.

If anyone know what could be happening it would be a great help.
Thank you very much and sorry if my english is bad.

Have a nice day.

**UPDATE**
As @JanezKuhar says I reemplace the imports in the pom. Now the dependencies looks like:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.1</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>cxf-integration-cdi</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.2</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.1.2.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.1.2.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
```

But it gives me now the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.cdi.CXFCdiServlet from [Module "deployment.projectEar.ear.projectWARModule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Comment: same ear works in tomcat but doesn't work in jboss right?

Comment: Why are you importing all the implementations of the JavaEE API parts (weld, CXF). Let the App server decide which to use and you just add the [`javaee-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api) artifact (which has all the interface definitions) to your root project with `provided` scope.

Comment: @yılmaz the .war works in tomat but doesn't work inside the .ear in the jboss.

Comment: @JanezKuhar i want to be sure that i understand, are you saying to coment the imports of the weld and cxf and reemplace it with the import of the javaee-api in the pom?

Comment: @LautaroSausa Yes

Comment: Why do you need this line `import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;` in `JaxRsApiApplication.java` - you can cross out one dependency in your WAR pom and make this example a tiny bit shorter.

Comment: Add [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf/3.0.0) artifact to your WAR module.

Comment: Also uncomment `weld-servlet` artifact.

Comment: @JanezKuhar added and uncomment the two artifacts. And comment the servlet part in the web.xml. The WAR module is deployed. Now the jboss doesn't throw error, but i cant access the rest services. Looks like they aren't accesible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly make this works.

As @JanezKuhar says I comment all the extra libraries in the pom and added two, now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>projectParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectWARModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>projectWARModule Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.apache.cxf.version>3.0.0</org.apache.cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>projectWAR</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>org.apache.cxf.impl</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment the servlet part and set the restEasy scan true, in the web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Now it works and I can access the REST servicies deployed in the jboss.

Thanks for the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your jboss-app.xml? Does maven create it?
In jboss-app.xml you (or maven) should create context root of your application.

> **jboss-app.xml**: Every EAR application should specify a unique string name for the class loader. It's from JBoss doc. [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Getting_Started_Guide/beta422/html/Configuration_Files.html)